# How do I upgrade SpamAssassin?

Tags: perl, spamassassin, cpan

When I try to update SpamAssassin, it says it has the latest version.

```
# cpanm Mail::SpamAssassin
Mail::SpamAssassin is up to date. (3.004004)
```

However, the latest version says it is 3.4.4. https://metacpan.org/release/Mail-SpamAssassin How do I update SpamAssassin to the latest version? Regular `cpan` also said it was up-to-date.

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SpamAssasin $VERSION format

$VERSION `3.004004` means version `3.4.4`.
Spamassassin encodes this way three positive integers into single number.

You can check "raw source" at metacpan.org.  Its contains `$VERSION = "3.004004";` and mentions `3.4.0` as previous version in embedded documentation.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::SpamAssassin  ->
https://metacpan.org/release/Mail-SpamAssassin/source/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm

> **KMCGRAIL / Mail-SpamAssassin-3.4.4 / lib / Mail / SpamAssassin.pm**
> […]
> our $VERSION = "3.004004";      # update after release (same format as perl $])
> […]
> Prior to version 3.4.0, calling srand() was handled by the SpamAssassin
> library.